# Is there a way to decompose a quantum circuit into a Clifford subcircuit and a non-Clifford subcircuit?

Tags: quantum-circuit, clifford-group, compiling

Is there any way of decomposing a arbitrary quantum circuit into two sub circuits, first of them being composed only of Clifford gates and the second one only of non-Clifford gates?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can make it even stronger than that. Any circuit can be approximated using the Clifford+T gate set. Then you can replace every T gate with gate teleportation through a T state. So any circuit can be decomposed into a Clifford part and a *trivial* non-Clifford part that does nothing except prepare many copies of the state $T |+\rangle$.

[image]

Comment: LOL thank you so much, I was just skimming through one of your papers some minutes ago hahaha. Do you know any reference on this so I can have deeper insights on this?

Comment: @ManuelGarcía In https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.08916 the idea is taken further in a way that increases performance while removing constraints on how the computation is packed into spacetime. The Clifford part ends up with no time ordering constraints and all the classical feedback is achieved by measuring "routing qubits" in the X or Z basis.